# How to trace in Common Lisp using gcl?

Tags: debugging, lisp, common-lisp, gnu-common-lisp

Is there some way to print out all the calls of your function to debug recursive programs?

Comment: GCL is not the best CL implementation around, have you tried, say, SBCL?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the TRACE macro.